# Tweetbot banner image pull down to zoom image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Tweetbot and Kickstarter for iOS uses a cool feature on user profiles that have a banner image. If you pull down on the `tableView` the image zooms.

I have it partially working using the following, it changes the height of the image, but strangely, not the width:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    CGFloat y = -scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.width+y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.height+y);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame));

}
```

Does anyone know how to recreate this effect?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Here is what I did:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"church-welcome.png"]];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.cachedImageViewSize = self.imageView.frame;
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.imageView];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 170)];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGFloat y = -scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (y > 0) {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.width+y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.height+y);
        self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.imageView.center.y);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Nic Hubbard I'm trying hard get this effect within a UIScrollView. The image is not sticking to the top. Can you help me. ?

Comment: @Priyatham51 - It has been over a year since I did this, so I don't remember the ins and outs of it anymore.

Comment: @NicHubbard I did achieve it with auto layout constraints as describe here ( http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/). 
Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Where is @property definition?
got minus from me.

Comment: The above is correct, but when the image is smaller than that of the actual size of the view then the image tends to aligned to the right hand corner. Can be solved by creating a UIImage view of the same bounds

Comment: @Priyatham51 If you change the last line to this the view will stick to the top:
self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.imageView.center.y - y);

Answer (score 1):

The above answer for Swift:

**Variable Decelerations:**

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
var cachedImageViewSize: CGRect!
```

**viewDidLoad:**

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
var cachedImageViewSize: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image-plane"))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 170)
    self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    self.cachedImageViewSize = self.imageView.frame
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.imageView)
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.imageView.center.y)
    self.tableView.sendSubviewToBack(self.imageView)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 170))
}
```

**scrollViewDidScroll:**

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let y: CGFloat = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if y > 0 {
            self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.width + y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.height + y)
            self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.imageView.center.y)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version of Nic Hubbard's answer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "header-image"))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 170)
    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.cachedImageViewSize = self.imageView.frame
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.imageView)

    self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y:self.imageView.center.y)
    self.tableView.sendSubview(toBack: self.imageView)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 170))
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y: CGFloat = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if y > 0 {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y, width: self.cachedImageViewSize.size.width + y, height: self.cachedImageViewSize.size.height + y)
        self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.imageView.center.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply resize the image view to fit the vertial space, while keeping the same aspect ratio.

Comment: I did that, and added the code above. It does kind of work, but for some reason the width never changes, even though the NSLog shows that the frame is changed. The height does get changed.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 version of Nic Hubbard's answer:

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
var cachedImageViewSize: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad(){

   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "church-welcome.png"))
   self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
   self.cachedImageViewSize = self.imageView.frame
   self.tableView.addSubview(self.imageView)
   self.tableView.sendSubviewToBack(self.imageView)
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 170))

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
var y: CGFloat = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
if y > 0 {
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.width + y, self.cachedImageViewSize.size.height + y)
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.imageView.center.y)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned solutions will actually not really provide the exact implementation of how it is in Tweetbot or Tinder [target's profile picture zooming].

I also had to solve this problem and the most perfect implementation I found is to use 2 main elements:

1) Tableview which has content inset

2) Imageview on top of that table view which has an outlet for top constraint and height constraint and which is on top of that empty space provided by the tableview content inset.

So first make sure to set the insets for the tableView and initial height constraint for the imageView. You can do this in viewDidLoad for example.

```
imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = view.frame.height * 0.3
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: view.frame.height * 0.3, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Then just listen to thew scrollViewDidScroll delegate method and modify the constraints accordingly.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if -contentOffset >= view.frame.height * 0.3 {
        //reset the top constraint
        topConstraint.constant = 0
        //make the imageview bigger by the additional content offset value
        imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = -contentOffset
    } else {
        topConstraint.constant = -(view.frame.height * 0.3 + contentOffset)
    }
}
```

You may need to inverse the signs according to how you've set your own constraints. And probably there's a way to optimize and not modify the constraints that often, but you get the idea.

Please also note that you need to:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Otherwise the image will be drawn on top of your first tableView cells [dependent on the image size it may come to cover to whole table view] because it is drawn outside its "bounds".